# What is the meaning of ToLower().Contains()

Tags: c#, string

What is the meaning of given below condition in C#:

```
if(!dr[4].ToString().ToLower().Contains("cash"))
```

Answer (score 2):

It starts by getting the 5th column in the data reader.  By default datareader turns object type, so whatever value returned is converted to string, so if it's:

> ABC

ToLower() makes it:

> abc

And contains checks for "cash" in the string, which is important for ToLower() because "cash" would not match "CASH" for the value.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what `dr` is (let's not assume things), this will do something if the outputted string **does not** contain the word 'cash'. Breaking this down it reads:

```c#
// do if *NOT*
if(!dr[4]

    // make a single string out of the fifth entry of dr (0 is the first)
    .ToString()

    // convert all characters in it to lowercase
    .ToLower()

    // check to see if it has the word 'cash' in it
    .Contains("cash"));
```

Answer (score 0):

this mean if the the fifth element of reader object `dr` when converted to lowercase string literal, does not contain
 the string `cash`.

Comment: dr[4] = "Cash"    if(!dr[4].ToString().ToLower().Contains("cash")){ true }else{ false } what is the out put

Comment: think a bit logically @Jiten. If `dr[4]` is `Cash` then expression evaluates to  `true` ,hence the output is `false`.

Comment: `false` again after the edit, @Jiten. :) . Any combination of upper and lower case , the output will be the same because you're calling the `ToLower()` method on a string and you'll get `NullReferenceException` if `dr[4]` is null.

Comment: What is the meaning of dr[0] = "CC-123" ; dr[0].ToString().Replace("AA","BB")